# How to set checkbox state in android

Tags: java, android

I am making an android app in which i made a custom adapter for list in which i have check box when i unchecked check box and go back to previous fragment then reopen fragment all the check box is checked.How to overcome this situation

Here is my java code

```
    ArrayList<Boolean> checked_list;

    public SettingsAdapter(Context context, int resource, RateItem[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        checked_list=new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        for(int i=0;i<this.getCount();i++){
            checked_list.add(i,true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_single,null);
        }

        ImageView img= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView title_txt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewtitle);
        TextView subtitle_txt= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewsubtitle);
        final CheckBox checkBox= (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxselected);


        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.australia);
        title_txt.setText(settings_array[position].title_rate);
        subtitle_txt.setText(settings_array[position].subtitle_rate);

        checkBox.setChecked(checked_list.get(position));

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!checkBox.isChecked()){
                       Set<RateItem> asSet = new HashSet<RateItem>(Arrays.asList(FragmentRateActivity.rate_array));
                       asSet.remove(FragmentRateActivity.rate_array[position]);
                       FragmentRateActivity.rate_array = asSet.toArray(new RateItem[]{});
                       checked_list.set(position,false);
                   }
                else {

                        /*Set<RateItem> asSet = new HashSet<RateItem>(Arrays.asList(FragmentRateActivity.rate_array));
                        asSet.remove(FragmentRateActivity.rate_array[position]);
                        FragmentRateActivity.rate_array = asSet.toArray(new RateItem[]{});*/
                        checked_list.set(position,true);
                }

          }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener instead of checkBox.setOnClickListener.
you are setting all checked_list to true in your constructor